# Get Top x Products using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, linq-query-syntax

I need to get the Top 10 records using Linq to Entities.

I need to bind the returned result into a `GridView` as follows"

```
Product Name  |   Product Description  |   Number of Items Sold

Item 1        |   Item 1 Description   |           24
```

As per the above, the items need to be stored in order, starting with the most item sold.

I've tried a couple of example such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288957/get-top-10-most-sold-products-between-date), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387110/linq-to-sql-get-top-10-most-ordered-products), and followed the [examples here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24448/LINQ-to-SQL-Samples).

The following is what I have tried so far:

```
public IQueryable GetTopTenProducts(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    return
        (from p in this.Entities.Product
         join pro in this.Entities.ProductOrder on p.ID equals pro.ProductID
         join o in this.Entities.Order on pro.OrderID equals o.ID
         where o.DateOfOrder >= startDate && o.DateOfOrder <= endDate
         select new
         {
             Product = p,
             Quantity = pro.Qty,
             ProductName = p.Name,
             ProductDescription = p.Description

         } into productQty
         group productQty by productQty.Product into pg
         let totalQuantity = pg.Sum(prod => prod.Quantity)
         orderby totalQuantity descending
         select pg.Key).Take(10);
}
```

This returns the products table as a whole, but I need to retrieve only the details pasted above.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have to change your last select `select pg.Key` to select what you want

for example: `select new { pg.Key.ProductName, pg.Key.ProductDescription, totalQuantity }`

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the whole products table because you are selecting `pg.Key` where `pg` is an [`IGrouping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with `Product` as the key and your anonymous type as the `IElement`.

So, you can refactor your final select to do something like this:

```
//rest of Linq query...
select new 
{ 
    pg.Key.Name, 
    pg.Key.Description,
    totalQuantity
})Take(10);
```